# How to broadcast intent manually ? android

Tags: android, google-analytics, broadcastreceiver, adb

I am following google analytics [campaign tracking test](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns#broadcast).
I am using the following command to send the referral intent :

```
./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER  -n "com.example.com/MyCustomCampaignTrackingReceiver" --es referrer "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

in `MyCustomCampaignTrackingReceiver.java` I try to log the intent referral extra :

```
String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
        Log.i("referrer",referrer);
```

but I just got the `utm_source=testSource` instead of `utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign`.

why ?

Comment: do `./adb shell 'am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER  -n "com.example.com/MyCustomCampaignTrackingReceiver" --es referrer "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"'` to avoid parsing of your adb command by local shell